# Dependent List of Values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

We are getting data in the following format in Excel:

[image]

As we can see in the above screenshot:

Item1 was mapped to only 1 value = Data1. (Column A and B)

Item2 was mapped to Data11 and Data12. (Column A and B)

Item2 Data11 and Data12 were also mapped to Item1.Data1 (Column A-B & C-D)

For this entire mapping, we are getting the value in

We want to Pivot the data and display it in the following format using VBA (We have 9 columns Item1 to Item9. For simplicity, we have added only 3 columns below):
[image]

We did brainstorm but did not get any answer. Please help us in which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you need to reorganize the data in to two columns (A and B), cutting every other pair of columns (on the right) and pasting under A and B. If so, that is trivial. Need clarification though. Edit: Are columns C and D in anyway related to columns A and B in the first table above?

Comment: Looks like a tree structure, item number is level. Data1 has 2 children Data11 and Data12. Data 11 has 2 children Data 21 and Data 31 etc. With 9 levels, class modules might be the way to go.

Comment: Hi Gokhan, It is like a tree structure. Data1 has two childs Data11 and Data 12. Data 11 inturn has childs Data21 and Data 22 and so on. We want to show all the combinations from the root till the leaf element in this tree. And Yes-> Columns C&D are related to Columns A&B

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class Module named `clsObj` to store the parent-child relationships.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public UID As String
Public Level As Integer
Public Children As New Collection

Sub addChild(child As clsObj)

    Dim bExists As Boolean, n As Long
    For n = 1 To Me.Children.Count
        If Me.Children(n).UID = child.UID Then
            bExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not bExists Then
        Me.Children.add child, child.UID
    End If

End Sub

Sub output(rngOut, ByRef ar)

    Dim child As Object, iLevel As Integer, n As Integer
    iLevel = Me.Level
    
    ' clear lower levels
    For n = iLevel To UBound(ar)
        ar(n) = ""
    Next
    ar(iLevel) = Me.UID

    ' print out if lowest level
    If Me.Children.Count = 0 Then
        For n = 1 To UBound(ar)
            rngOut.Offset(0, n - 1) = ar(n)
        Next
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(1)
    Else
        For Each child In Me.Children
            ' recurse down next level
            child.output rngOut, ar
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Scan the input sheet creating objects. Store the objects in a dictionary (one for each level) for subsequent retrieval

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub process()

   Dim wb As Workbook, wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
   Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long, i As Integer
   Dim sUID As String, iLevel As Integer
   
   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set wsIn = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

   Dim dict(9) As Object, key, obj1 As clsObj, obj2 As clsObj
   For i = 1 To 9
       Set dict(i) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   Next

   iLastRow = wsIn.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   For r = 1 To iLastRow
    
       iLevel = Mid(wsIn.Cells(r, "A"), 5)
       sUID = wsIn.Cells(r, "B")
       If dict(iLevel).exists(sUID) Then
           Set obj1 = dict(iLevel).Item(sUID)
       Else
           ' new item
           Set obj1 = New clsObj
           obj1.UID = sUID
           obj1.Level = iLevel
           dict(iLevel).add sUID, obj1
       End If

       ' child
       iLevel = Mid(wsIn.Cells(r, "C"), 5)
       sUID = wsIn.Cells(r, "D")
       If dict(iLevel).exists(sUID) Then
            Set obj2 = dict(iLevel).Item(sUID)
       Else
            ' new item
            Set obj2 = New clsObj
            obj2.UID = sUID
            obj2.Level = iLevel
            dict(iLevel).add sUID, obj2
       End If
       obj1.addChild obj2

    Next

    ' result to sheet2
    Dim ar(9) As String, rngOut As Range
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    wsOut.Cells.Clear
    For iLevel = 1 To 9
        wsOut.Cells(1, iLevel) = "Item " & iLevel
    Next
    Set rngOut = wsOut.Range("A2")
    For Each key In dict(1)
        dict(1)(key).output rngOut, ar
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```